# Lilypond: natural+flat accidental in front of the note

Tags: lilypond, accidentals, engraving

I can not find a way to have both a natural and a flat accidental in front of a single note.

[image: image of natural and flat before a note]

How can I get this in LilyPond?

Comment: Why do you want it at all? Such a notation is not used very much these days (I think). However, Lilypond by default uses this if there has been a double accidental before. So if you just write `beses4 bes4`, the first note will have a double flat and the next one a natural + flat. Outside of these cases, such a notation would be extremely rare or nonexistent in actual use.

Comment: In American notation?

Comment: @Ramillies  In fact this notation is quite common when the previous time that pitch was in the music it was either sharped or double-flatted.   this  natural + {flat, sharp} notation is useful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
\tweak Accidental.restore-first ##t
```

https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/snippets/pitches#pitches-force-a-cancellation-natural-before-accidentals

Comment: Great!  I needed this too.  I found a part in Bruckner's 7th symphony (Adagio) that used this to specify a `cis!` after a `cisis` in the previous measure.

Answer (score 6):

As Ramillies says in the comments, this is a pretty rare occurrence; I'd be curious to see the context of your example. But the main reason I can think of these accidentals happening is to cancel out a prior double accidental (with the natural) while still giving a single accidental to the new pitch.

But LilyPond has various [accidental styles](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/displaying-pitches#automatic-accidentals) that automates how accidentals appear in your scores. Depending on your specific example, you may find that one of these styles fits your needs the best.

Comment: here it is the song. It is a transcriptions of an Indian Mantra of the 70's

Comment: https://www.srichinmoysongs.com/hai-mane-mahi-pare

Comment: As I understand it, a prior double accidental is a valid reason for cancellation, but the other accidental type (sharp in this case) might be the much more frequently encountered one.

Comment: I don't think one would use it to cancel a double accidental while giving a new single *accidental* to the same pitch, but rather in cases where a key signature has a single flat and it's necessary to cancel a double-flat and play a note with the single flat *that's in the key signature*.  Some editors would regard the use of a single flat mark as adequate for the purpose, but performers may not consistently recognize that a note with a single-flat accidental should sometimes represent a higher pitch than a note which isn't marked with any accidental.  The natural makes things IMHO clearer.