# Lilypond: multiple glyphs in front of a note

Tags: lilypond

I can use a markup to put several glyphs under and over a note with _\markup ^markup but I do not know how to place glyphs in front of a note. Something similar to [Natural+flat accidental in front of the note](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/118539/lilypond-naturalflat-accidental-in-front-of-the-note) but with arbitrary glyphs.

It would be even better (but not necessary) if the placement were identical to that of accidentals also in case of chords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to get this would be to abuse fingerings:

```
{
  \set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
  
  <c''-\finger\markup \override #'(font-encoding . "latin1") "my mup">
}
```

If you do want the collision resolution of accidental columns and you do not need both accidental and custom glyph for any note you can abuse Accidentals:

```
{
  \override Accidental.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
  \override Accidental.font-size = #-3
  <\tweak Accidental.text \markup\vcenter "mup1" c'!
   \tweak Accidental.text \markup\vcenter "mup2" d'!
   \tweak Accidental.text \markup\vcenter "mup3" f'!
   \tweak Accidental.text \markup\vcenter "mup4" b'!
   \tweak Accidental.text \markup\vcenter "mup5" c''!>
}
```

Else one would need some extra effort for creating some  custom engraver.